# Was Jean-Hugues Anglade mildly wounded in the Thalys shooting?

Tags: france

Several news sources reported and are still reporting French actor Jean-Hugues Anglade was mildly wounded in the [2015 Thalys train attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Thalys_attack). He is quoted as claiming that the wound was a cut on his hand that he received while breaking the glass covering an emergency button on the train.

- [People](http://www.people.com/article/french-train-attack-Jean-Hugues-Anglade-interview)

> "We were in car 11, the last. The armed man looked towards us, he was determined. I thought it was the end, we were going to die, he was going to kill us all," says Anglade, who badly cut his finger breaking into the train's emergency box to sound the alarm and apply the brake.

- [ITV](http://www.itv.com/news/update/2015-08-21/interior-minister-meets-actor-wounded-in-thalys-shooting/)

> The actor, who starred in the films Killing Zoe and Betty Blue, was lightly injured when he broke the glass to activate the train's alarm.

Was Anglade wounded? Was it a cut caused by breaking glass cover to an emergency button?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) Given there are multiple news reports making the claim, and quoting him, what angle are you doubtful about? Do you suspect he was never injured? Do you suspect he never pushed the emergency button? Are you suggesting people have over-exaggerated the injury?  Just trying to work out what sort of answer you would find satisfying.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Hugues_Anglade) has three other references that confirm this.